# Is it possible to delete an international google url from my Chrome history?

Tags: google-chrome

My friend visited [google.it](http://google.it), and now whenever I go to starting typing in "google.com" in the address bar, google.it comes up instead. It's not a big deal, but it's kind of annoying to have to type out the whole url. I deleted all the google.it pages from Chrome history, but it still comes up. Is it possible to remove "google.it" from the history of things that I've typed directly into the URL bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Omnibox, scroll to the wrong URL with the arrow keys and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, the entry will be removed.

Comment: This is the answer. Additionally, you can also just type your search into the chrome omnibox and search that way.

Comment: @Tyler: That's what I normally do, but sometimes I want things like Google Instant that aren't part of Chrome (yet).